# Ios 7 popover does not work

Tags: ipad, ios7, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to update my app so that it properly works on iOs7.

in iOS 5 & 6 this worked perfectly:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"popover"])
{
    FavoritesViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
    CGFloat width = 200.0;
    CGRect rect = [vc.tableView rectForSection:[vc.tableView numberOfSections] - 1];
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetMaxY(rect);

    if ([segue isKindOfClass:[UIStoryboardPopoverSegue class]])
    {  
        _filterPopoverController = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
        [_filterPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)];  
        [_filterPopoverController setDelegate:self];
    }
}
}
```

I use this to check if its already on the screen

```
- (IBAction)touchedFilterButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender 
{
    if (_filterPopoverController == nil)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"popover" sender:self];
    }
    else
    {
        [_filterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        _filterPopoverController = nil;
    }
}
```

if i remove this line

```
    _filterPopoverController = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
```

It works but i cant set the width/height and there is no check if its on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was iOS7 is not so "Forgiving"

i call

```
    _filterPopoverController = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
```

after

```
CGFloat width = 200.0;
CGRect rect = [vc.tableView rectForSection:[vc.tableView numberOfSections] - 1];
CGFloat height = CGRectGetMaxY(rect);
```

height is always 0.000 because its not "shown" yet, so i had to replace the segue after calling the other view controller and set the width.
And i removed the subclass part because its already a subclass for sure

```
FavoritesViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
_filterPopoverController = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];

CGFloat width = 200.0;
CGRect rect = [vc.tableView rectForSection:[vc.tableView numberOfSections] - 1];
CGFloat height = CGRectGetMaxY(rect);

[_filterPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)];
[_filterPopoverController setDelegate:self];
```